# To display category,sub-category,sub-sub categories and postname in url permalink in wordpress php

Tags: php, wordpress, url, categories, permalinks

If a post has three categories.parent category,sub category and sub-sub category.when i click on the post i want the url like

> **category/subcategory/sub-subcategory/postname/**

I updated my custom permalink structure as

> **/%category%/%postname%/**

But i m not getting the required permalink.I searched a lot and i got some functions.I used that rewrite rules function.nw the post url is coming correctly.bt it redirects to 404 page.Please help me:

Answer (score 0):

Goto Settings->Permalink Settings-> Custom Structure
Add this as custom structure. 
http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/%category%/%postname%/
Hope this will work for you.